# Where are documents physically stored on Liferay 4?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I'm working with a legacy application that's using Liferay 4. They have a bunch of files on display using the Documents and Media portlet. I can see all of these files listed but when I go to view them or download them I get errors. I even tried going into the Admin Console and got the same issue. I can see all the files listed but when I go to download them I get errors.

There are some recent files from last month that were uploaded and those files are able to be viewed. So I get the feeling something happened a few months ago that deleted these files. From what I've gathered the files are stored on the server and the file information is stored on the database. If that's true it would explain why the files are being listed but not view-able/downloadable; if they were deleted from the server but their meta-data remains in the database allowing them to be listed.

According to this page, https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/6387093, the files should be under *data/document-library* but I believe that's only for Liferay 6.

So where are these files being stored for Liferay 4?

Answer (score 3):

Default settings for a portal come from a file `Portal.properties`. For Liferay 4, I found this documentation:
http://content.liferay.com/4.2/doc/installation/liferay_4_customization_guide/multipage/ch01s02.html
It states:

```
#
# Set the directories where documents are stored. This is now deprecated
# because documents are stored in Jackrabbit.
#
dl.root.dir=/home/liferay/documentlibrary/root/
dl.version.root.dir=/home/liferay/documentlibrary/vroot/
```

and

```
##
## JCR
##

jcr.initialize.on.startup=false

jcr.workspace.name=liferay
jcr.node.documentlibrary=documentlibrary
jcr.jackrabbit.repository.root=/home/liferay/jackrabbit 
jcr.jackrabbit.config.file.path=${jcr.jackrabbit.repository.root}/repository.xml
jcr.jackrabbit.repository.home=${jcr.jackrabbit.repository.root}/home
jcr.jackrabbit.credentials.username=none
jcr.jackrabbit.credentials.password=none
```

In newer versions of Liferay, the defaults can be overridden in the file `portal-ext.properties` or in the database.

You might look for hints at these places.